# Queue generated many time for SqlTableDependency C#

Tags: c#, sql

For Sql Table Dependency every time new Queue get generated in the service broker Tag in SQL server .

I am getting notification from the SQL using C# language used Sql Table Dependency techniques.

need only one queue in service broker .

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Newest version fix this problem.
Just try to get latest package.